# Failed to lock variable $Project::Databases

Tags: variables, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a Project parameter called `Databases` which is a `Project` parameter in SSIS of data type `String`. The variable in itself contains a hard coded XML document, i.e.:

```
<dbs>
    <data>
      <db>database1</db>
      <store>store1</store>
    </data>
    <data>
      <db>database2</db>
      <store>store2</store>
    </data>
</dbs>
```

and I use it in a `foreach loop` in SSIS where I iterate these databases and corresponding stores.

My foreach loop is configured as:

```
DocumentSourceType: Variable
DocumentSource: $Project::Databases
EnumerationType: ElementCollection
OuterXPathStringSourceType: DirectInput
OuterXPathString: /dbs/*
InnerElementType: NodeText
InnerXPathStringSourceType: DirectInput
InnerXPathString: *
```

and I then use `Variable Mappings` to have index `0` correspond to the variable `User::DatabaseName` and index `1` to correspond to `User::StoreKey`.

This *works* when I execute the package from `SSIS`. The SQL statement variable I use with these values gives the correct output etc.

The problem is when I try to execute this using a `SQL Agent Job` I get the error:

> Failed to lock variable "$Project::Databases" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found". This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables Collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The Variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created

but the variable *should* be created - it is merely a hard coded variable after all.

When I  have googled this issue possible solutions has been that:

The variable is not of type string (*which it is in my case*)

or

The user from which the SQL Agent Job is executed from does not have the correct permissions (*in my case it is ran by a sysadmin on the database for which I read the data to and msdb and SSISDB*).

Comment: What deployment model are you using?

Comment: @digital.aaron I simply deploy each package by right clicking them an choosing `Deploy package...` in Visual Studio SSIS 2016. Seems logical to test another deployment option. Shall I deploy the whole Project instead of each package? I can't test at the moment as I don't have access to the Environment from home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS will only use Project parameters when the package is deployed using the Project Deployment Model. If you're using the Package Deployment Model, you should change your package to use a configuration instead of Project parameters.